# Show and hide different elements by class with the same JS function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a js or jq function to hide and show items by class with two variables, the class of the items to be shown and the class of the items to be hidden.

I can't make it works. Do anyone know what happens?

```js
function ShowHide(ShowClass, HideClass) {
  document.getElementsByClassName(ShowClass).show();
  document.getElementsByClassName(HideClass).hide();
}
```

```css
.ABChidden,
.DEFhidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="ABCvisible" type="button" onclick="ShowHide('ABChidden', 'ABCvisible');">
      Click Me to show ABC
    </button>
<p class="ABChidden">I'm ABC</p>
<button class="ABChidden" type="button" onclick="ShowHide('ABCvisible', 'ABChidden');">Click Me to hide ABC</button>

<hr>

<button class="DEFvisible" type="button" onclick="ShowHide('DEFhidden', 'DEFvisible');">
      Click Me to show CGE
    </button>
<p class="DEFhidden">I'm DEF</p>
<button class="DEFhidden" type="button" onclick="ShowHide('DEFvisible', 'DEFhidden');">Click Me to hide CGE</button>
```

Comment: `show` and `hide` are jQuery mehods. You cant use them on a JS Object. Try `style.display = "none"`

Answer (score 3):

You can't use jQuery methods like `.css()` with DOM objects, you need to create a jQuery collection object with `$()`.

```js
function ShowHide(ShowClass, HideClass) {
  $(`.${ShowClass}`).show();
  $(`.${HideClass}`).hide();
}
```

```css
.ABChidden,
.DEFhidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="ABCvisible" type="button" onclick="ShowHide('ABChidden', 'ABCvisible');">
      Click Me to show ABC
    </button>
<p class="ABChidden">I'm ABC</p>
<button class="ABChidden" type="button" onclick="ShowHide('ABCvisible', 'ABChidden');">Click Me to hide ABC</button>

<hr>

<button class="DEFvisible" type="button" onclick="ShowHide('DEFhidden', 'DEFvisible');">
      Click Me to show CGE
    </button>
<p class="DEFhidden">I'm DEF</p>
<button class="DEFhidden" type="button" onclick="ShowHide('DEFvisible', 'DEFhidden');">Click Me to hide CGE</button>
```

or use ordinary JavaScript DOM methods and set the `style` property of all the selected elements.

```js
function ShowHide(ShowClass, HideClass) {
  Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName(ShowClass)).forEach(el =>
    el.style.display = 'block');
  Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName(HideClass)).forEach(el =>
    el.style.display = 'none');
}
```

```css
.ABChidden,
.DEFhidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<button class="ABCvisible" type="button" onclick="ShowHide('ABChidden', 'ABCvisible');">
      Click Me to show ABC
    </button>
<p class="ABChidden">I'm ABC</p>
<button class="ABChidden" type="button" onclick="ShowHide('ABCvisible', 'ABChidden');">Click Me to hide ABC</button>

<hr>

<button class="DEFvisible" type="button" onclick="ShowHide('DEFhidden', 'DEFvisible');">
      Click Me to show CGE
    </button>
<p class="DEFhidden">I'm DEF</p>
<button class="DEFhidden" type="button" onclick="ShowHide('DEFvisible', 'DEFhidden');">Click Me to hide CGE</button>
```

Comment: Ty very much, im a noob at javascript and i was getting a headake with this :D

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the display property of the ShowClass and HideClass elements one by one. It can be easily done using loop.

```
function ShowHide(ShowClass, HideClass) {
  elementsToDisplay = document.getElementsByClassName(ShowClass);
  elementsToHide = document.getElementsByClassName(HideClass);

  [...elementsToDisplay].forEach(elem => (elem.style.display = "block"));
  [...elementsToHide].forEach(elem => (elem.style.display = "none"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, if you run

```
document.getElementsByClassName('ABChidden')
```

it returns a list.
Secondly, `show` and `hide` are both not functions, so it won't run anyway

Try this:

```
function ShowHide(showClass,hideClass){
   document.getElementsByClassName(showClass)[0].hidden='false';
   document.getElementsByClassName(hideClass)[0].hidden='true';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Place each section in a container.
2. In the onclick listener, send in the clicked element with 'this' (this = the button element).
3. In the method `toggleVisibility`, go up a node to the parent element - the `.container` and toggle it's class.
4. Set CSS classes to `.show` and `.hide`, based on if the parent have the class `.hidden`.

```js
function toggleVisibility(element) {
  element.parentNode.classList.toggle("hidden");
}
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}

.container.hidden > .show {
  display: none;
}

.container.hidden > .hide {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <button class="show" type="button" onclick="toggleVisibility(this)">
      Click Me to show ABC
    </button>
  <p class="hide">I'm ABC</p>
  <button class="hide" type="button" onclick="toggleVisibility(this)">Click Me to hide ABC</button>
</div>


<hr>

<div class="container">
  <button class="show" type="button" onclick="toggleVisibility(this)">
      Click Me to show CGE
    </button>
  <p class="hide">I'm DEF</p>
  <button class="hide" type="button" onclick="toggleVisibility(this)">Click Me to hide CGE</button>
</div>
```